# javascript - hide text before /

Tags: javascript

I need hide all words and numbers before /

Results must be only "130ml"

I try this code, but this code hide text behind / a need before.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.price-measure span'), function(el) {
  var addy = el.innerHTML;
  el.innerHTML = /[^,]*/.exec(addy)[0];
});
```

```html
<span class="price-measure"><span>2 438 Kč / 130 ml</span></span>
```

Comment: Hide from CSS or delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me with a split

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.price-measure span')]
  .forEach(el => el.textContent = el.textContent.split(" / ")[1]);
```

```html
<span class="price-measure"><span>2 438 Kč / 130 ml</span></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this

```
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.price-measure span');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var text = divs[i].innerHTML;
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf("/") + 1);
    divs[i].innerHTML = text;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` method to split the strings.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price-measure span')
  .forEach(el => {
    let addy = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = addy.split('/')[1];
  })
```

```html
<span class="price-measure">
    <span>2 438 Kč / 130 ml</span>
</span>
```

Comment: i try this, but cosole say undefined

Answer (score 0):

The script I've written adds a `span` around the text you want to hide, set to `display: none`. The advantage of this approach is that you can make the text visible again later – you haven't completely deleted it.

```js
var textToEdit = document.getElementById('text-to-edit');

var originalText = textToEdit.innerText;
var newText = '<span id="hide">';
var slashReached = false;

for (i = 0; i < originalText.length; i++) {
    
  if (!slashReached) {
    if (originalText[i] == '/') {
      slashReached = true;
      newText += '</span>';
    }
  } else {
    newText += originalText[i];
  }
}

textToEdit.innerHTML = newText;
```

```css
#hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="price-measure">
  <span id="text-to-edit">2 438 Kč / 130 ml</span>
</span>
```